# What is Stock or Overflow Pit? Is it a terminology in geography? What is the correct word for it?

Tags: geography, geomorphology, terminology

I have an excel file that I have to make the join with another table that has a column listed of different kind of feature types. This was done by someone else who did GPS'ed and spell that word and handed it out to me to do the spatial join with a point layer.

What does Stock or Overflow Pit? Is it related to geography or geomorphology term? Is there another word that is similar to it? I tried to Google it but with no luck. I looked it up on the image on the google to find it and still have no luck. Would someone out there helped me what they are or what does it look like?

Edit: This was post in the GIS StackExchange and it's not approiate to post it since it is not related to GIS.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188827/what-is-stock-or-overflow-pit-is-it-a-terminology-in-geography?noredirect=1#comment284729_188827

Comment: I don't understand what you have and what you're trying to do. Where do these terms appear? What are the tables?

Comment: @Michael  I was asking anyone in here if there is an another term for stock or overflow Pit; however, I talked to my co-worker so I think it is not related to geology or geomorphology and but it is obviously nomenclature specific to something that I can't look it up.

Comment: Might be a question for StockOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I think I found what it is...

It is a tank that has a stock pit on the allotment. The tank usually about 30 feet radious and has a windmill.  It looks like this

http://www.panoramio.com/photo/9687839